# Kohana Class not Found

Tags: module, kohana

I downloaded a **Flickr module** from [kohana-modules.com](http://kohana-modules.com) and when I tested on my local server worked perfectly. But when I uploaded to a remote server, to the same directory as the default Koahan modules, I got a `"ErrorException [ Fatal Error ]: Class 'Flickr' not found".` The default Kohana modules are working as expected. I'm using Kohana 3.2.2.

Any pointers to why this is happening?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using this module: https://github.com/jeanmask/flickr/tree/alpha-0.3? If it so, than it is not compatible with the version of Kohana that you are using.

Comment: i'm using https://github.com/jeanmask/flickr. it worked on my local server using the kohana 3.2.2 build

Comment: Module is enabled in Bootstrap.php? If so, then provide more info on error you are getting.

Comment: in my bootstrap:
'flickr' => MODPATH.'flickr'

error:
http://imgur.com/aQwR98X

Answer (score 3):

I experience that exact same behaviour with both Kohana 3.2 and 3.3 if a dynamic reference to a class can not be resolved by the autoloader on a Linux server. Mainly because *filesystems used by Mac OSX and Windows are case insensitive but a Unix/Linux based server is not*. What operating systems are your local and remote servers running on?

Since you are using Kohana 3.2 and the main branch of the mentioned flickr module is erroneously named 3.1/master but contains 3.3 PSR-0 updates *try using the 3.0 branch instead*: https://github.com/jeanmask/flickr/tree/3.0/master

Heads up: even better would be to fork the github repository, build a valid Kohana 3.2 branch that holds all changes but does not contain PSR-0 modifications and state a pull request.

Comment: +1: For possibly confused Kohana users: I had a similar problem today. A module couldn’t find the class `Message_Core`. I had to change not just the file `core.php` to `Core.php`, but also the directory `message` to `Message`. I spoke to Zombor today, and he said that `auto_load_lowercase` will not be supported in the next release (3.4) so we can’t use that either.